# php array is taken as null when it is not

Tags: php, arrays

I have passed an array called `$items` to my view in order to print it. Take a look:

```
<?php echo "<br>First print: " . $items;    

if ($items != null): 
    echo "<br>Second print: " . $items; 
php endif;?>
```

The final output is:

> First print: Array

As you can see, `$items` is not null, however, the second message is never printed. Is there something wrong with my server?

**Edit**:

I can evaluate `$items` with empty function, but I need to evalute it with `null comparator` because this variable can be null.

**Edit 2:**

The `$items` can take be take the following values when is passed to the view:

- null: `$items = null;`
- array: `$items = array();` or `$items = array('a', 'b');`

Comment: Use print_r or var_dump instead echo. Or if you want echo somestr.somearr use this instead: echo "<br>First print:".print_r($items, 1);

Comment: I know @bksi, my point of view is the `if` statement. The concatenation is just for debug porpuses.

Comment: `if (!empty($items))` - but i see your point.

Comment: items is array, not null. How you want to enter this if statement?

Comment: if you didn't add `<?php` to the start of every line your syntax would be a lot clearer: http://codepad.viper-7.com/eRUYEJ

Comment: If you want to compare with null is better using !== instead !=

Comment: `php array strage bahviour` -  Terrible question title, you might want to correct that.

Comment: @TheBlueDog, my bad! Apologies.

Comment: The question is not clean. From the code you post it is not clear how your variable would be null

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/GL1e1f notice the notices

Comment: Ok OK, I have update the question in order to improve it. (Taking note of every guy here)

Comment: Use `!== null` instead.

Comment: @bksi, can you provide your comment as an answer in order to accept it? and why the `!=` comparator is incorrect in my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare with null it is better using !== instead !=

This way you tell PHP to use strict comparision and both sides should be identical (type and value)

Else you can get wrong results if the array is empty (for example)

More for php comparisions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 4):

If PHP array has no values in it, i.e `count($array)` is `0`, it gives `true` when compared with null.

Make sure you have atleast one value in your array.

Comment: Or use strict comparison (`!==`)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand the use of `!=` in arrays. Thank you.